# How use and run Swift 2.3 on command line

Tags: swift

How do you start Swift on the command line? And how do you compile files on the command line with Swift 2.3? Since I updated to Xcode 8 I get Swift 3 by default.

```
$ xcrun swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.46.2 clang-800.0.38). Type :help for assistance.
```

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**

To use Swift 2.3 prefix `swift` with toolchain selection via `xcrun`:

```
xcrun --toolchain "com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_2_3" swift --version
```

prints:

```
Apple Swift version 2.3 (swiftlang-800.10.12 clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Use [swiftenv](https://github.com/kylef/swiftenv) to install and switch between Swift versions.

Install using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
brew install kylef/formulae/swiftenv
```

Configure environment (zsh, for example):

```
echo 'if which swiftenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(swiftenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.zshrc
```

List available versions:

```
swiftenv install --list
```

Install Swift 2.2:

```
swiftenv install 2.2
```

Comment: Running the above command: "xcrun --toolchain "com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_2_3" swift --version" does nothing for me. After execution I did "swift --version" and still says 3.0, and when I execute my Swift 2.3 file it tries to compile it as Swift 3.0 ..... thoughts?

Comment: @AndrewJohnson To use another toolchain you should prefix `swift` with `xcrun --toolchain "com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_2_3"`.